# What is the difference between 'plant', 'mill', and 'factory'?

Tags: difference

Take a look at this, I would say, mess.

> **plant**
>
> A place where an industrial or manufacturing process takes place.

(from [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/plant))

> **mill**
>
> A building fitted with machinery for a manufacturing process.

*(from [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mill))*

> **factory**
>
> A building or group of buildings where goods are manufactured or assembled chiefly by machine.

*(from [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/factory))*

Isn't it the same thing described by different words? I'm sure that there are some differences, even if they are not delineated in Lexico

Comment: A mill turns the complex into the simple (grain to flour), but a factory turns the simple into the complex (flour to bread). I’m not sure where plants fit in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed frustrating to find distinct words with dictionary entries that overlap to such a degree.

To get at the differences you will need to dig a little deeper, and maybe research the etymology. For example one attempt to [differentiate](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-plant-and-factory#:%7E:text=They%20can%20mean%20different%20things,grain%20is%20milled%20into%20flour.) **plant** and **factory**

I can think of two distinct situations

1. You see an industrial complex, a sign outside says "Car Assembly Plant" or "Biscuit Factory" or "Woollen Mill". Is there a way to deduce which of plant, factory or mill was selected before you see the sign?
2. In conversation you want to refer to such a complex, and do not know its allocated name. Will your meaning be clear if you choose the "wrong" word? Is there a best default to use?

Going back to some origins:

Mill has a quite specific root in the grinding, such as wheat into flour, hence windwills. The term broadened to other forceful industrial processes. When I was a boy in Yorkshire my town had buildings where wool was processed into cloth, we called those Woollen Mills, and Lancashire had its Cotton Mills. Hence the stereotypical:

> Trouble dahn t'mill

I would say that "mill" implies processing some basic ingredient into something that itself is used by another industrial process. The original meaning comes from grinding, mill-stones grind grain to flour.

- Flour Mill produced flour then used by bakers to make bread and cakes.
- Paper Mill processes wood to paper which is then passed to printers
- Steel Mill processes ore and metals to pre-formed steel sheets and rods for use in other industrial processes.
- Woollen Mill processes wool to cloth used by tailors and milliners.

A factory has connotations of manufacturing, creating complex objects.

A plant is not a word I remember being used in this way (as opposed to a living, growing, organsim) as a boy in the UK, but is certainly common now. I view plant as something larger than a single factory, a huge car manufacturing plant for example. I think **plant** can describe places where things are processed rather than manufactured, for example a water purification plant.

So to name something a mill we have relatively clear concept. A plant seems a broader term than factory. For things such as a water-processing plant, it's clear that plant is a better term. But why are the Nissan Assembly Plants plants rather than factories? I can think of no reason other than scale.

My default would be to use the word factory. I'd be confident of being understood.

Comment: The "mess"  was not providing semantic differences that in reality exist. That is, I was referring to a fault of the dictionary, not the language. That's what I meant

Comment: Why is cloth not complex? I still don't understand what is the difference between the terms (between 'plant' and 'mill', in particular)

Comment: What about, say, fertilizers? Is it complex enough?

Comment: What is the second-best option? It is important to use synonyms from time to time

Comment: I have adjusted my answer in the light of your comments. I hope it helps a little.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev if you do not know which to choose plant is probably the most generic. Obviously you need to avoid plant if it is preceded by a type of plant so cotton mill is definitely not a cotton plant.